# HTML table split in 2, displayed on the same page side by side

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an HTML table of 2 columns I want the visitors to be able to sort (title, date) and filter. I found a very large jQuery that can do that, but the table is very long and narrow, so I would like to split it in half and display the halves side by side. On small screens the second half should move bellow the first. After filtering the second half could just stay empty.

Other methods that do that to lists don't have any effect. If there is a direct solution with JavaScript to "display it" in 2 halves that'd be great.

I was thinking, maybe it's possible to create 2 containers that use pagination to display the first half of the table on the left side, and the second page, with the second half to the right?

Also, I'm sorry I'm asking for much, but could you make it work with "iframe"? Ideally I'd edit only one HTML page, with the table embedded in several others.

I used the jQuery by SpryMedia found at:
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

I don't know JavaScript, so all I could do is tailor it a bit to my case (2 columns table). The table length will vary in time, so if it'll always compute the number of rows and split itself in half would the great. 2 columns of 200px take less then the half of the max container width.

If this doesn't work I will have to revert to lists, but then I have a problem of sorting entries both by title and date (only one criteria can be used with this method). So I'd have to hide an 8 digit prefix (as date) in the title string however I didn't find on the internet a jQuery that can:

1. sort asc. and desc. the entries by the (hidden) first 8 characters (digits) for date;
2. sort by the 9th character (first letter of the title);
3. and have a filtering option for any combination of characters.

With the table I have the aforementioned problems solved, but I can't fit the table in 2 side by side halves to take less space.

Thank you!

Bellow is a simplified version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        .center {
            margin: auto;
            width: 60%;
            border: 3px solid #73AD21;
            padding: 10px;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <script>$(document).ready(function() {
                            /*// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
                                $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
                                    var title = $(this).text();
                                    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );} );*/
 
                            // DataTable
                                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                                    initComplete: function () {
                                    // Apply the search
                                    this.api().columns().every( function () {
                                var that = this;

                                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                                    that
                                    .search( this.value )
                                    .draw();}} );} );}});} );
            </script>                       
            <table id="example" class="" style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;width:150px">Place <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;width:150px">Date <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sydney</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2010/12/22</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>2010/11/14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2011/06/07</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2010/03/11</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>2011/08/14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sydney</td>
                    <td>2011/06/02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2009/10/22</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2011/05/07</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>                      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to build it yourself? If so, can you post your code attempt? If no attempt has been made, it's hard to justify building this table out for you.

Comment: When you are having problem with your source make sure to post your source code aswell so others can have a look at it, You can use Insert Code option from editor or you can use pastebin to post your code if its too large to fit in.

Comment: My table is generic. I'm having problems with the jQuerry (edited my original post) as it was made only to filter and sort the columns.

I'm don't know JavaScript so I can't offer any code made by myself.
It is important to keep the sorting and filtering function for the entire table even if it is split in half. So I was thinking it is easier to keep the table (and jQuery) as a whole and only to fool the html page into displaying 2 screens of the 2 table halves.
Of course, when filtering, the other half might be empty and take no screen space (bellow the first half on small screens).

Comment: Also, the jQuery can paginate, so maybe split screens (in one container) for the 2 table halves can act as 2 pages displayed at once, side by side?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, solved here:
[Sort HTML list by 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003035/sort-html-list-by-2-criteria)

is to have a list of strings where (for two column data) the string is formatted as `Title - YYYY/MM/DD`

Breaking the list in two and displaying it side by side, is possible with CSS `column-count:2;` unlike the table, and the function to sort it by Date (second half of the string), thanks to @Cristian Sarghe and W3 Schools, is as follows:

```
function sortListDate() {
                var list, i, switching, b, c, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
                    list = document.getElementById("List_Id_Name");
                    switching = true;
                    // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
                    dir = "asc"; 
                    // Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
                while (switching) {
                    // start by saying: no switching is done:
                    switching = false;
                    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                    //substr(list.getElementsByTagName("LI").length - 8);
                    // Loop through all list-items:
                    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
                        //start by saying there should be no switching:
                        shouldSwitch = false;
                        /* check if the next item should switch place with the current item, based on the sorting direction (asc or desc): */
                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) { 
                        /* checking the string for Date after "- " */
                        /* if next item is alphabetically lower than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;}}
                    else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) {
                        /* if next item is alphabetically higher than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                        shouldSwitch= true;
                        break;}}}

                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done: */
                    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    // Each time a switch is done, increase switchcount by 1:
                    switchcount ++;}
                else {
                    /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;}}}}
```