# Sort HTML list by 2 criteria

Tags: html, jquery, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of strings containing a title and a date.
The first jQuery sorts the list alphabetically by the first character (from W3 school)
The second jQuery however is supposed to sort by the second half of the string containing a Date.
I changed a bit the first jQuery to do that, by looking for a '- ' in the string.
It does sort the list, however the problem is that it sorts the dates by grouping the results with the title (city name). So there are dates sorted for every repeating instance of city names, not a true sorting for random city names.

It appears as if it sorts the Dates by keeping the list sorted by the first letter (original jquery).

The jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aprilius/638jbq7o/3/

And the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <style>
        .center {
            margin: auto;
            width: 70%;
            border: 3px solid #73AD21;
            padding: 10px;
            -webkit-column-width: 240px;
            -moz-column-width: 240px;
            column-width: 240px;
            column-gap:20px;
            -moz-column-gap:20px;
            -webkit-column-gap:20px;
            column-count:2;
            -moz-column-count:2;
            -webkit-column-count:2;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <button onclick="sortListAZ()">Sort by Title</button>
            <button onclick="sortListDate()">Sort by Date</button>
            <input type="text" id="filterbar" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
            <script>
                function sortListAZ() {
                    var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
                        list = document.getElementById("example");
                        switching = true;
                        // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
                        dir = "asc"; 
                        // Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
                    while (switching) {
                        // start by saying: no switching is done:
                        switching = false;
                        b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                        // Loop through all list-items:
                        for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
                            //start by saying there should be no switching:
                            shouldSwitch = false;
                            /* check if the next item should switch place with the current item, based on the sorting direction (asc or desc): */
                        if (dir == "asc") {
                            if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            /* if next item is alphabetically lower than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                                shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;}}
                        else if (dir == "desc") {
                            if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            /* if next item is alphabetically higher than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                            shouldSwitch= true;
                            break;}}}

                    if (shouldSwitch) {
                        /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done: */
                        b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
                        switching = true;
                        // Each time a switch is done, increase switchcount by 1:
                        switchcount ++;}
                    else {
                        /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
                        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                            dir = "desc";
                            switching = true;}}}}
            </script>
            <script>
                function sortListDate() {
                var list, i, switching, b, c, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
                    list = document.getElementById("cuprins");
                    switching = true;
                    // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
                    dir = "asc"; 
                    // Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
                while (switching) {
                    // start by saying: no switching is done:
                    switching = false;
                    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                    //substr(list.getElementsByTagName("LI").length - 8);
                    // Loop through all list-items:
                    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
                        //start by saying there should be no switching:
                        shouldSwitch = false;
                        /* check if the next item should switch place with the current item, based on the sorting direction (asc or desc): */
                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) { 
                        /* checking the string for Date after "- " */
                        /* if next item is alphabetically lower than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;}}
                    else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) {
                        /* if next item is alphabetically higher than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                        shouldSwitch= true;
                        break;}}}

                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done: */
                    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    // Each time a switch is done, increase switchcount by 1:
                    switchcount ++;}
                else {
                    /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;}}}}
            </script>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
                    input = document.getElementById("filterbar");
                    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                    ul = document.getElementById("example");
                    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";}}}
            </script>
            <ul id="example">
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2011/04/25</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tokyo - 2011/07/25</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2009/01/12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2012/03/29</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tokyo - 2008/11/28</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2012/12/02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2012/08/06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tokyo - 2010/10/14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2009/09/15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2008/12/13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2008/12/19</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2013/03/03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2008/10/16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2012/12/18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2010/03/17</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2012/11/27</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2010/06/09</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2009/04/10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2012/10/13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2012/03/26</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2011/09/03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2009/06/25</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York - 2011/12/12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sydney - 2010/09/20</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London - 2009/10/09</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edinburgh - 2010/12/22</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Singapore - 2010/11/14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2011/06/07</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco - 2010/03/11</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                      
    </body>
</html>
```

SOLVED: The full jQuery, fixed by @Cristian Sarghe, to sort a list of entries (strings) as `Title - YYYY/MM/DD` both by title and date, ascending and descending is as follows:

```
function sortListDate() {
                var list, i, switching, b, c, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
                    list = document.getElementById("cuprins");
                    switching = true;
                    // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
                    dir = "asc"; 
                    // Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
                while (switching) {
                    // start by saying: no switching is done:
                    switching = false;
                    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                    //substr(list.getElementsByTagName("LI").length - 8);
                    // Loop through all list-items:
                    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
                        //start by saying there should be no switching:
                        shouldSwitch = false;
                        /* check if the next item should switch place with the current item, based on the sorting direction (asc or desc): */
                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) { 
                        /* checking the string for Date after "- " */
                        /* if next item is alphabetically lower than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;}}
                    else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')) < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().slice(b[i+1].innerHTML.indexOf('- '))) {
                        /* if next item is alphabetically higher than current item, mark as a switch and break the loop: */
                        shouldSwitch= true;
                        break;}}}

                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done: */
                    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    // Each time a switch is done, increase switchcount by 1:
                    switchcount ++;}
                else {
                    /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one semicolon-like type problem.

You are using the `slice('- ')` function on `string` prototype.
You should pass an index to it, not a string.

Technically, just use `b[i].innerHTML.indexOf('- ')` using `b[i]` and `b[i+1]` where necessary, as a parameter for `slice(...)`, instead of the string.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6L41v3p/

Comment: I'm sorry, but the method doesn't solve the problem: the list is still grouped by the first letter (city name) while the date is not sorted at all.
Did I understand well? I have to switch `slice('- ')` with `indexOf('- ')` ?

Comment: @aprilius I've edited the answer adding a JSFiddle. Just search for the `indexOf` function usages, that's the only difference.

Comment: WOW, thank you very much!!! I will update the page with your answer. Thank you!